# How to get name/string from either RingtoneManager or content:// uri

Tags: android, audio, alarm, picker, ringtone

I am starting the RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER, override the

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        int code = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 999) {
            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            Log.d("selected tone" , uri.toString()));

            if (uri != null) {
                this.chosenRingtone = uri.toString();
            } else {
                this.chosenRingtone = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

All I get in my log is the context uri like `content://media/internal/audio/media/33`
How can I get the alarm name string like "Cesium" or whatever was selected? Thank you.

Comment: query this ContentProvider and use these columns http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html

Comment: `Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
String title = ringtone.getTitle(this);`